# mongodb match ,filter and pull

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

need to create the query where $match , filter , map , condition and then pull all should be done .

**collection structure:**

```
    "ArryObj": [{
    "dat": [-84.2, -83.9, -84.9, -85.3, -86.8, -85.6, -84.6, -86.4],
    "Date": "26-05-2021",
    "Time": "13:02:42",
    },{
    "dat": [-90.2, -83.9, -84.9, -85.3, -86.0, -85.0, -84.2, -86.4],
    "Date": "26-05-2021",
    "Time": "13:02:42",
    },
    {
    "dat": [-100.2, -83.9, -90, -85.3, -86.0, -85.0, -84.2, -86.4],
    "Date": "27-05-2021",
    "Time": "13:02:42",
    },
    {
    "dat": [-80, -79.9, -63, -79.3, -78.0, -76.0, -77.2, -79.4],
    "Date": "28-05-2021",
    "Time": "13:02:42",
    }
]
```

- Need to find into dat[] where any element <-80 and display only that documents
- count the result
- then delete the matched document

Comment: Provide expected output for the sample data provided

Comment: Hi 
- Need to find into dat[] where any element <-80 and display only that documents and count 2 

```
{"ArryObj": [{
        "Date": "26-05-2021",
    "Time": "13:02:42",
    },{
      "Date": "26-05-2021",
      "Time": "13:02:42",
    },
    {
      "Date": "27-05-2021",
       "Time": "13:02:42",
    }]},count:2,
}
```
Finally delete the above two array